# Работа с мета-данными аудио. Перенести название файла в имя

Tags: python

Можно ли сделать алгоритм который перенесет название mp3 файла в имя файла? И как это реализовать?
после имени вставить название.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а чем, по-вашему, «название файла» отличается от «имени файла»? изложите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]. // кстати, после этого мгновенно станет ясно, и «как это реализовать».

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: привел скрин. Они в разных столбцах.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8948/9210255